# How to open pdf file on particular area of the screen in Android

Tags: android, pdf, webview, filereader

I have requirement at which, on my screen header label is there and on the bottom 
    of the screen one button is there. I want to show PDFs file between this label 
    and button how I will implement this? When I am trying to open PDFs It's taking full 
    screen space.

```
      File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "mypdf.pdf");


        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(file.exists() + "!!");
        //InputStream in = resource.openStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
                System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

        //below is the different part
        File someFile = new File("java2.pdf");
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(
                Uri.parse("file://" + getFilesDir() + "/java2.pdf"),
                "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try, but you should try to use Fragments in the Ativity you want to show the PDF. From the original site:

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can  combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragments in multiple activities.

Use a single fragment between the button and the header and open PDF on it. Maybe it will help you

Comment: Thanks but on fragment how I will show pdf because pdf open in it's own container. I want to show it in my UI not on pdf container.

Comment: @MDFAIZANWAR I think the problem is that you demand the aperture of PDF to external app with this call:

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

So you can't handle your custom view easly.